# How to use inversify.js in react redux application on the service layer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, inversifyjs

I would like to use inversify in react-redux application but **only** in the service layer and not via componenet

I have the service of a setting that need to call to API (Http service) 
I would like a kind of provider that will give me the option to call settingsService.get() in the actions.ts file

How do i initialize the objects of all my services

my actions.ts file:   I guess to bring container here and use conainter.get... is a bad practice

```
export const increment = () => (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch({
    type: INCREMENT
  });
};
```

My settings Service

```
@injectable()
export class SettingsService implements Settings {
@inject(TYPES.Test) private testService!: Test;
  get() {
   // some api call
    return this.testService.test();
  }
}
```

My inversify.ts

```
const container = new Container();

function init() {
  container
    .bind<Settings>(TYPES.Settings)
    .to(SettingsService)
    .inSingletonScope();
  container
    .bind<Test>(TYPES.Test)
    .to(TestService)
    .inSingletonScope();
}

export { container, init };
```

My question :

1 - where do I initialize the services? is the definition in iversify.ts is ok? do I need to initialize the container in index.ts on the react app? now I call init() in index.ts

2 - how do I call to settingsService in the actions.ts ( action.ts is not class-based) is a redux action function

3- should easy to test

### My stack

React, redux, typescript